# ActiveX Combo boxes self generating by the 100s

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

Excel is stacking 100s of combo boxes in the same spot on one of my sheets.

I have coding in place with the combo boxes, but it is only to adjust the size of the font.

I also have tried to delete the boxes manually but when I cleaned up 254 of them I switched tabs. did some work, saved and came back to sheet one and there were 504 combo boxes.

Here is the macro for the combo boxes. I am using the ActiveX version.

```
Private Sub ComboBox3_Change()
    Dim cb As ComboBox

    With ActiveSheet

        Set cb = .OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.ComboBox.1", Link:=False, _
                                 DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=322.5, Top:=11.5, Width:=176.5, Height:= _
                                 61.5).Object

        cb.Font.Size = 20

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: runaway add tied to a change, an add is a change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code , add a Combobox in the same place everytime that a event called

> Change

is triggered , So everytime u change the value of the Combo , another one is placed in front of that.

To stop that , stop adding , instead

```
set cb = .oleobjects.add()
```

use

```
   set cb = .olebjects("HEREPUTYOURCHECKNAME")
```

.

```
Set cb = .OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.ComboBox.1", Link:=False, _
                         DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=322.5, Top:=11.5, Width:=176.5, Height:= _
```

Comment: Okay so I have this changed, but now I'm getting a "named arguments not allowed" error with the height?


`Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
 Dim cb As ComboBox

    With ActiveSheet

        Set cb = .OLEObjects(ComboBox1)(ClassType:="Forms.ComboBox.1", Link:=False, _
                          DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=322.5, Top:=11.5, Width:=176.5, Height:= _
                                 61.5).Object

        cb.Font.Size = 20

 
    End With

End Sub`

Comment: Remove the " _ " before the height measure

Comment: its "Combobox1" with a string

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad - this worked except now i get a compile error: Named arguments not allowed.

Comment: @RonanVico - I am not sure where you are talking about with the combobox1 and string..

Comment: Actually, if all you want to do is change the font, lose all of that `(ClassType:="Forms.ComboBox.1", Link:=False, _ DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=322.5, Top:=11.5, Width:=176.5, Height:= _ 61.5)` as @Ronan Vico says, you just need `set cb = .olebjects(ComboBox1)` (assuming `ComboBox1` actually exists)

Comment: Started completely over after deleted all comboboxes. So this code works except for if I back out the state name and leave it blank, or select from the list it give me a Error 438 Object Doesn't support this property or method. 

`Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
  Dim cb As ComboBox

    With ActiveSheet

        Set cb = .OLEObjects.ComboBox1(ClassType:="Forms.ComboBox.1", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=322.5, Top:=11.5, Width:=176.5, Height:=61.5)

        cb.Font.Size = 20

    End With

End Sub`

Comment: I guess just running the combobox without the code and using the properties box is also a good option too.